# $\sqrt{1-x^2}|P(x)|\le 1$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Let $P(x)$ be a real polynomial with degree $n$ such that $\sqrt{1-x^2}|P(x)|\le 1$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$.
>   Prove that $|P(x)|\le n+1$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$.

This question was posted some years ago at Mathlinks forum and I'm pretty sure it came from some old AMM (American Mathematical Monthly).

I believe this problem can be solved using Chebyshev polynomials, but I'm not able to make any progress.

Comment: well, for n = 0, P(x) = 1 is a counterexample.

Comment: @user159517 Thanks! It's $n+1$, not $n$.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on why you think chebyshev polynomials are useful here.